# What is the fastest way to create a 90° joint?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I often want to create joints like this:

[image]

Since I end up making these more than a little, I'd like a fast way to do it (i.e. on the order of < 10 seconds)

I've found a couple tools which come close to being the ideal solution, but I've had some problems with them as listed below:

- When using the spin tool I usually end up having to fiddle with the location for a while in order to to get a natural curve:

  [image]

  Are there any techniques to expedite this process of fiddling?
- The bridge tool is nice because I can precisely specify where both ends of the joint will be, however I often end up with subtly uneven joints, probably due to my initial mesh being not quite square.

  [image]

  Is there a fast way to correctly line up the initial edge loops in a way that will result in an even joint?

Comment: @cegaton I've tried that, but as far as I could tell it didn't seem to support the rounded joints that I want.

Comment: Bridge edge loops works wonderfully. To fix the uneven joints use the smoothness slider.

Comment: @cegaton I did, but it remained uneven.. (or maybe it's just me)

Comment: Yes, it remains uneven. Then how about building from a 1/4 torus? Though it's not what you are asking. I think it would also be fast enough to create such model. :P

Answer (score 11):

The [spin tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/modeling/meshes/tools/spin.html#spin) is well suited for creating joins:

[image]

[image]

Spin <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> it works best (expected results) in orthographic mode. The selected parts of the mesh will be rotated around the 3D cursor. The 3D cursor should precisely set vie the properties panel <kbd>N</kbd>.

[image]

The last operator settings allow to adjust the angle and steps:

[image]

If you focus more on modelling speed than accuracy the the bend tool could also be useful: [How does the bend tool work?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21763/how-does-the-bend-tool-work)

Answer (score 5):

This is a combination with more mesh and less curve:

1. Create a cube;
2. Bevel an side edge;
3. Extract a path;
4. Convert to curve by <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, set depth and resolution.
5. Convert it back to mesh by <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

a curve with a bezer circle as bevel object:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice :) I'm mostly interested in mesh solutions though, as I normally want to do this while working on existing mesh models. I'm also looking for speed, and I doubt I could do this and join it into my mesh object very quickly.. Useful trick regardless, will keep it in mind.