# How to achieve an evenly distributed 90° turn?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to bend "#Object 1" to something like "#Object 2" but with less triangle clutter and an equally distributed inner turn.

I tried the "Spin" tool on "#Object2" and a "Bevel" at the inner edge but that's not working very well as one can see in the image.

[image: screen shot of blender showing a 90° bend]

Any hint how I could achieve an evenly distributed 90° turn?

Comment: somehow related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-create-a-90%C2%B0-joint

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy way to do that is with spin selection around cursor. Put the cursor where the radius of the bend should be, select the edges which you want to extrude and hit Spin button in Tools panel. You can adjust the spin angle and number of segments in spin properties panel or by hitting <kbd>F6</kbd> button right after spin operation.

Note that the spin operation is relative to the view angle.

[image: Spin]

Comment: That worked after some fiddling with the cursor, thanks a lot Denis!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a path and the curve modifier for some real good results as shown below.

To do this use the start up file(box, camera, light).
In front view set the box X, Y, Z values as follows 3, 2, 5.
Next, create a 'path' from the tools section and have it aligned to the front view after-which you can shape it to a general 90 degree angle for the box to follow.
Next select the box and enter 'edit' mode and subdivide it at least 3 times. (you can play with even 1 subdivision if you want).
Go back to 'object' mode with the box still selected and put the 'curve' modifier on it and select the 'nurbspath' from the object dropdown and make sure the deformation axis is set to X.
Now use the 'grab' transform and move it along the X axis until it comes in contact with the 'path' and it should deform quite nicely along that path as show in my picture. (the picture shows a lot of the setting I just spoke about if you look closely)

[image: screen shot of blender]

Comment: Can you add a bit more info to your answer? Some newer blender users may still not know what to do after reading you answer.