# How to approach the modeling of duct work, piping, wiring?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, bezier-curves

I'm wondering how to approach duct work, piping, and wiring?

In the past, I have used the spin tool to make corners, but I find it very cumbersome.

How do you do duct work and piping? I have seen people use curves, but I find it's hard to get straight 90 degree angles or just uniform angling across the whole model. It's also hard connecting piping together if they started from different locations.

Here's some reference:

[image: Something like this]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Curves and objects with array modifiers set to follow the curve

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21761/599

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To create basic connections you can use any or a combination of the following 3 Techniques:

- **Pipe Joints**, part of the Mesh > Extra Objects Add-on

Open the user preferences window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in 2.79, or Edit>Preferences in 2.8) Navigate to the add-ons section.

Enable the Add Mesh: **Extra Objects** Add-on

[image]

[image]

You'll have a new item on the add menu to create pipe joints.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

As of version 2.79 and 2.8 Pipe Joints are accessible on Add>Mesh>Mechanical>Pipe Joints.

[image]

[image]

At creation time, each of the tools have a different set of options to refine the angle, diameter, etc. (if the tool tab is not open press <kbd>T</kbd> to make it visible or press <kbd>F6</kbd>

Keep in mind that once you make any further transformations, those original parameters cannot be reset ([read this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/is-there-any-way-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created)).

[image]

---

- **Connect different segments**.

To connect two cylinder segments that have the same number of vertices, select the end edges and use [**Bridge Edge Loops**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bridge_edge_loops.html?#bridge-edge-loops), and adjust number of cut and smoothness.

[image]

---

- **Curves**

To create large sections and more intricate paths , create a base shape for the pipe.

[image]

And use it as a Bevel object on a curve:

[image]

To deal with sharp turns adjust the control points by pressing <kbd>B</kbd> and selecting Vector. The width of the curve can then be ajusted by changing the radius of a control point.

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about the extra options in the bridge edge loops operator. Thanks for mentioning that!

Answer (score 10):

Two other ways to make pipes: Vertex extrusion and Spin tool.

A fun way to make pipes is first to create with simple **vertex extrusions**:

[image]

Then bevel the angles (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and tweak the parameters in the *Operator* box):

[image]

Convert your mesh to a [Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) (header menu → *Object* → *Convert To* → *Curve*):

[image]

Then bevel your curve to give it thickness (*Properties panel* → *Object Data* → *Geometry* → *Bevel*). After that, reconvert to mesh, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, and a smooth shading...

[image]

Instead of converting to curve you could give your mesh a *Skin* modifier (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to change the vertices radius):

[image]

When you're good, apply the *Skin* modifier, give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Another way is to use the **Spin** tool. Switch to top view, select the edge, put your 3D cursor where the center of the rotation is supposed to be:

[image]

Select the *Spin* tool:

[image]

Rotate the edge, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to constrain to 10° by 10°, tweak the Operator box parameters if necessary:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  With my limited knowledge of Blender and looking at the different ways I am thinking I would use the Vertex Extrusion method as it seems to me to be the easiest the 'wrap the 'pipe' around corners on the fly and correctly follow the sides of the docks.- I am wondering how to get the lengths of the pipe to 'fit' around the docks and the vertex extrusion appears to be the easiest way. Please tell me

Comment: "how to get the lengths of the pipe to 'fit' around the docks", I'm not sure to understand where is the difficulty, maybe elaborate?

Comment: Well consider the letter E as docks and that each leg is wide (actually my docks have the appearance of the letter from overhead). For this example (of learning) I want to add 'pipes' (say) all around the periphery of E and I was thinking that I need to know how long each leg is allowing for the fact that the 'line' will be expanded into a pipe shape later and also allowing for clearance at the 'corners'. What if I make each part (between the bends ) the wrong length,  is  there a method to change the length of each 'leg' a a later time. Also how to change direction for the extrusion.

Comment: you can always move the parts you want, also you can fatten/shrink your pipe, etc... you need to give it a try and you'll see the advantages and limitations I guess

Comment: Thanks but do I need to add a new vertex (and extrude it) at every change in 'direction (on the X, Y axis in my model) or can a single added vertex by made to extrude for a set distance and then extrude in a different direction. The first image in the tuition above for using vertex extrusion shows a 'line' going in a number of different directions

Comment: could you please edit and show an example in your original question? The problem with curves is that you can't create multiple directions (a vertex can't be connected to more than 2 vertices), is it your problem here? It doesn't seem to be the case in your original question

Comment: NO my 'problem' is not 'here'. I don't want multiple directions just one direction but changing consider the letter L. The bottom leg changes directions from the horizontal to the vertical. Maybe the axis can be stipulated when extruding. Sorry its late and run out of time to check. Will have a look in the morning.

Comment: Next morning. OK YES you can change the direction when extruding (using LMB) but can you FORCE the extrude to go along ONE AXIS ONLY (my eye hand co-ordination is not wonderful)?

Comment: when you extrude (E) you can stipulate the direction with X, Y or Z if this is what you're asking

Comment: Yes but I was (trying to) select an axis after selecting extrude from the (edit mode) icon which doesn't seem to allow selection of an axis BUT pressing E (for extrude) then then the axis (X, Y or Z) DOES.  A bit tricky. Do keyboard commands often work differenetly from selecting a 'command' via an icon?

Comment: Most of the time I use the shortcuts, but if you use the extrude icon you can still press the axis you want while dragging the yellow gizmo

Comment: Thanks but .I find that MUCH more difficult to do. More difficult than pressing the E key and the the key for the axis I want.