# How to make the cube follow the nurbs path

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am newbie to blender. I have modified the default cube and added a NURBS path and slightly changed its curve. Now I would like the cube to follow along the NURBS path. For this I used the Curve modifier. But no matter what I tried, the cube does not follow along the curve!

I saw the following post but it did not help!

- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Deforming_Meshes_using_the_Curve_Modifier
  -

[How to get a flexible tube to follow a curved path?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49559/how-to-get-a-flexible-tube-to-follow-a-curved-path)

Screenshot
[image]

Also attached is the .Blend file.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Rich! Moving the Subdivision modifier as the first one, did the job. Now I understand that having more detailed geometry is the key. I even tried an alternative approach, without the subdivision modifier, by using Loop cut and adding more vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Curve modifier requires some more detailed geometry to curve the cube - otherwise you still only have 8 vertices and 6 faces to spread over the cube. Fron your screenshot you do appear to have a Subdivision Surface modifier but it is *after* the curve - click the ‘up arrow’ in the top-right of the Subdivision Surface modifier panel to move it above the curve. You’ll then need to increase the View number of subdivisions - set it the same as Render (ie, 2). This will affect the shape of your cube as it will cause corners to be rounded off - so click Simple (which divides without affecting the overall shape) rather than Catmull-Clark (which divides and blends faces and edges into each other).

Increase the number of subdivisions (View and Render) for more detail along the curve.