# Create Outer Envelope of a Complex Object?

Tags: modifiers, 3d-printing

Given an complex shape that has unwanted inner structure inside the skin, I'd like to create an outer 'envelope' of the surface that ignores that internal structure. e.g. imagine a bunch of intersecting pipes, and wanting a solid that is just the outside surface, rather than the interior mess of walls at pipe-join spots.

So I'd hope to lose the non-manifold bits and end up with a sealed structure. On a simple shape I can do it manually, but on a complex one it would be prohibitively time consuming.

I've heard there's a shrink-wrap function somewhere, but I assume if you did a shrink-wrap of say a square bird-cage, you'd end up with a cube rather than the open space for the bird, which I'd also need.

Rgds
Ross.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of the question and add more information. Images of the object you want to wrap would be helpful to understand your question.

Comment: If I understand correctly you'd like to model joint between 2 similar meshes. I don't think you can use shrinkwrap in case when you'd like to create a joint. Maybe related in case of pipes - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring. Another shapes may require another approach

Comment: Sounds like Boolean operations might be what you want, but hard to tell without more info. Also Boolean operations have very strict requirements and limited situations where they work well, so some care would have to be taken. Please edit your question and provide more details about your question, like some screenshots or if possible a Blender file.

Comment: Could you please add some screen captures so that we could understand a bit more how is the mesh you are talking about ?