# How would I smooth a 90 degree pipe angle?

Tags: modeling

I would like to smooth out this pipe. I know that I should have made it out of a curve. Is there any way to smooth the pipe?

[image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring/42594#42594

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Indeed it would be easier to deal with this type of geometry using [Bezier Curves instead](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better/66367#66367).

Otherwise just use the *Bridge Edge Loops* operator.

Erase the straight corner faces, select both end edge loops, call the *Bridge Edge Loops* from the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> / <kbd>F3</kbd> search, then adjust the number of cuts and smoothness as desired.

[image: Bridge]

Comment: I had no clue that you could add more cuts while bridging edge loops, thanks!