# Connect two walls with a curve

Tags: modeling, mesh

If I have this,

[image]

How can I connect the two walls in the following way?

[image]

I mean, I would like to understand how to connect the two parts with a curve.

Comment: This may help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66733/how-would-i-smooth-a-90-degree-pipe-angle/66735#66735

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do that easily with the *Bridge Edge Loops* operator, just select both faces capping the ends you wish to join, and press <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> and search for *Bridge Edge Loops*.

Adjust parameters as desired, most importantly the *Number of Segments* and *Smoothness*.
[image]

Comment: Why do you erase faces on the wall ends first? Bridge should work on face as well.

Comment: You are right, totally forgot that you could bridge directly from faces. Fixed text and image, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: The `B` shortcut must be your custom setup as `B` should activate box select. There isn't normally a shortcut for bridge edgeloops.

Comment: Damn, you are right, I got so used to my custom keymap that I totally forgot I changed it. Fixed now, thanks for noticing

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I too use to have a custom theme and a few shortcuts, but got tired of constantly changing everything for each answer; so now I just run the defaults for keyboard and theme.

Comment: This is probably unpopular opinion but after all these years I could never get used to Blender's default right-click-select. It started with a simple customization like that, and ended up spreading into an overall more "standard" and familiar keymap, including stuff like click-drag for *Border Select* and `123` for switching between Vertex Face and Edge selection mode and many more. Its a dependency, I'd have serious trouble going back now.