# How to use bridge edge loops to make a pipe bend in Blender 2.8/9

Tags: loop

I'm trying to bridge two edge loops in Blender 2.8 to make a curved pipe. I was able to do this in 2.79 but I cannot get it work in 2.8.

After setting profile to 0. Setting it to -1 makes it look crumpled. Either way I cannot seem to make a nice arc.

Is there another way to bend a pipe?

Same settings as Robin Betts

[image]

Comment: Hello :). It seems your *profile factor* is rather high, have you tried setting it at zero?

Comment: I set it to zero and it's a little better. I tried -1 but then it gets worse again.

Comment: Probably you have non-uniform scale. Apply the scale with Ctrl+A in Object Mode, then try again.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79697/connect-two-walls-with-a-curve/79701#79701  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66733/how-would-i-smooth-a-90-degree-pipe-angle/66735#66735

Comment: Scaling fixed it! Thanks FFeller and others

Answer (score 1):

These settings work for me..

[image]

You certainly don't want a profile factor if you want the diameter of your pipe to be constant along its length.

It's only trial and error that gets me to go with 'Blend Surface' and this 'Smoothness'.. maybe someone who knows the code can tell us what the maths is?