# How do I connect these faces?

Tags: modeling, objects

How do I add a curve connecting the two faces? I’m attempting to model a wing, so this would be the “elbow”, so it can’t be *perfectly* smooth, but I literally just started blender and the tools are **extremely** overwhelming. And I suppose, for future reference, I should ask: what kind of tool should I use for the membrane? Can I lock things to a parent point so it doesn’t create gaps when I finally animate it?
cube.006 is the upper one, while "cube" is the lower one.

please explain it to me like I'm stupid this has taken ALL of my brainpower I'm pretty sure I'm losing my mind.
[image: the problem]

Comment: Maybe use a union boolean operator, then manually create faces using 'F' in edit mode

Comment: See settings in this answer re using bridge edge loops (as answered) to add loop cuts to the elbow geometry.   https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/166692/15543

Answer (score 3):

If both cylinders have the same amount of vertices on their head faces, you can

1. select both objects
2. CTRL-J -> Join
3. tab -> edit mode
4. select edge loop of both faces

[image]

4. Edge -> Bridge edge loops

[image]

result:

[image]