# Modelling a steel structure frame

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves, workflow

I am trying to design a steel structure frame, like this:

[image: steel structure frame]

Obviously, I can model individual beams of different length and arange them, however, it feels like there should be an easier way.

My second attempt was to use a curve and extrude along path (as in [Extrude along path](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2866/extrude-along-path)), which works well, except that a curve can not have a three-junction, and corners look weird:
[image]

Is there some way to get this right? Maybe a special form of the wireframe modifier, which allows me to give a bevel object, just as I do with the curve?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53475/how-can-i-extrude-curve-shapes-onto-curve-without-tapering/53486 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66733/how-would-i-smooth-a-90-degree-pipe-angle/66735

Comment: Hi there, I am involved in addressing this issue in Blender. This is still in development but closing in on a solution and that'd be great if you could provide some feedback here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/curve-to-mesh-node-even-thickness-feedback-thread/27271  - Thanks in advance!