# How can you edit simple tubes?

Tags: modeling

So i learned how to create simple tubes. Now i wonder if there´s a way to edit them further and use sculpt mode for example. Using the subdivision surface modifier on a path i can´t apply it. Is it possible to transform the path into a cylinder? I know you can simply create one, but that´s not the point.[image]

Comment: How are you going to edit them? To grab some parts to change curvature or alike? Or to add some bumpiness or crevices? If the former, edit them before converting to mesh (in Object Data tabof the Properties editor), if the latter, check if topology is even, convert to mesh and go with Multires modifier.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring/42594#42594

Comment: a wanted to sculpt on the tube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a curve to a mesh 'as viewed' in at least two ways:

1. Alt+C -> Mesh from curve
2. In user preferences, under addons, enable 'Corrective Shape Keys', then there will be an operator available for converting this and other types of objects to clean meshes with modifiers applied. In the spacebar menu, it will be named 'Duplicate and Apply All' (I like setting  a shortcut to Ctrl+Shift+D, YMMV)