# How exactly you use Extra Objects like N-Pipe?

Tags: objects, add-on

[image: pipe joints]

Is this a type of Extra Objects meshes that are there just for convenience? I imagine the pipe screensaver in old school windows, but then again that is very much algorithmic. Not something one would create manually (I might be wrong).

I guess I probably can use this to create some kind of typography pipes manually.

What would be interesting is to see pipe works made in Blender.

Comment: Like most tools in Blender they are there for convenience, I am guessing this would be quite useful for someone working in any sort of sci-fi scene with lots cables and ducts, or some factory or industrial setting with lots of pipes, steampunk stuff, a maze or pipe-system, tunnels, for games or interactive applications. Who knows

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring/42594#42594