# How to make a cross tee pipe fitting in Blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh

When I try to do it, it looks VERY sloppy.  I assume there's an easy way, I just don't know how.

Here is kind of what I'm going for:

[image]

It can't have a lot of faces though so the Subdivide modifier is out of the question.  I don't mind if it's a little blocky but I just can't figure out how to merge cylinders like that.

Comment: Not at a computer to make a full answer but extra objects addon has a pipe joint object.  That is the fastest way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to aproach the modeling of duct work, piping, wiring?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring)

Comment: Use the suggested addon and select Pipe_Cross-Joint

Comment: That's not what I want though.  Those are sharp.  This has a much more gradual curve into each other

Comment: Smooth curving surface will be available only with adidng new geometry, no matter if with Subsurf or any other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Final:

I do know that you said you don't want to use Subdivision Surface modifier, but just check those numbers:

[image: final]

### Steps:

[image: steps]

1. Select four faces around a **Cube**.
2. In **Tools Panel** choose **Extrude Individual** and enter desired number or move your mouse (I've entered '1').
3. Delete selected faces.
4. Add **Subdivision Surface** modifier.
5. *(Optional)* Add **Solidify modifier**.
6. *(Optional)* In Data tab check **AutoSmooth** and set **Angle** to **60 degrees**.