# How can be mesh like cylinder curved like this with precise degrees not by hands?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I've done this by hands. Can be this done otherwise easily?

[image]

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring)

Comment: Use Bezier curve objects