# How to bend a tube with consistent thickness?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

Modelling a Newton's cradle, but i can't seem to create the stand shape:

[image]

I have tried to use a path, and got this result:

[image]

It looks pretty good until you reach the top, where it is flat. The thickness is not consistent. So i am looking for an alternative way to make the stand. What are some ways to make this type of shape?

Comment: Related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring/42594#42594

Comment: beveling a bezier curve path with  a bezier circle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a circle. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Circle*. The default has 32 vertices I change it to 16 vertices (You can decide however many you like).

[image: Circle]

<kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and move it off center. Select all vertices press <kbd>G</kbd> to grab and the axis you want to move it on (in my case) <kbd>X</kbd>.

Extrude it up. Press <kbd>E</kbd> and the axis you want to extrude it (in my case) <kbd>G</kbd>.

[image: Extrude]

Place the Cursor next to the top and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to create the radius.

[image: Radius]

Add a *Mirror* Modifier and check off the *Clipping* box.

[image]

Extrude to the middle. Press <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

[image]

*This could also be accomplished with a Bezier Curve.

Comment: thanks a ton man! this was really important because i am putting it in an asset pack and it looked bad.

Answer (score 5):

Start by creating your base cylinder, duplicating it and rotating it 90 degrees, and place it where you need it, so that you end up with two straight pieces to be connected.

[image]

Then use [**Bridge Edge Loops**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#bridge-edge-loops), add the number of desired cuts and setting the smoothness to have the correct profile and avoid overlapping geometry.

[image]

Comment: +1 worked for me. In Blender 2.8, select edge loops and then right-click for Bridge Edge Loops.

Answer (score 0):

Bridging both edge loops will work however, make sure both objects are joined together prior to bridging the edge loops. If the pieces are not joined together using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd>, it will not work.