# Joining two cylinder at 45 degree angle

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to join these two cylinders together. I tried the pipe joint mesh but the diameter will not go small enough.

Equally, is there is a way to extrude the face of the top cylinder vertically downwards at an angle but that the face is level?

I am new to Blender so realise this seems very simple but any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: you can activate the LoopTools addon if it's not already the case, then select the two edges and right click > LoopTools > Bridge

Comment: Or, Bridge Edge Loops, and its options?

Comment: yes, but it looks like it is not available in Vertex Selection mode (in my 2.8 version at least)? Not sure why...

Comment: thank you for all the advice!

Comment: it's not clear if you want a round transition between your 2 cylinders or you want to keep a sharp angle?

Comment: @moonboots  even from Vertex Mode, I just need to call up the ol'-fashioned Ctrl-E edge menu, in my 2.83 release.. I'm _still_ missing a lot of the old standard shortcuts.. :)

Comment: oh ok so it's not just me  ;)

Answer (score 6):

To make a pipe bend the quickest way is to use the *Bridge* tool: Select both the 2 rims vertices and right click (context menu) > *LoopTools > Bridge* (you may need to activate the *LoopTools* addon before), or in *Edge Select* mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*. Then in the *Operator* box, set the bend as you want.

[image]

If you want to create a pipe bend but want to keep a sharp edge, the new (2.8) *Mirror* modifier allows you to do it easily: Create your cylinder, create an empty, give your cylinder a *Mirror* modifier with the empty as *Mirror Object*, choose (in my case) *Axis > X, Bisect > X, Flip > X*, move and rotate the empty until the cylinder and its mirrored merge the way you want (keep pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> during the rotation if you want it to be 10° by 10°).

[image]

The *Shear* tool also allows you to create sharp bends but it's not convenient if you want precise angles or if your object is not perpendicular to the axis.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Was the look I was hoping for!

Answer (score 3):

Select the top loop of vertices on the bottom section and the bottom loop on the. Upper section,

Press F3 and type **bridge edge loops** and play with the offset.

Read [How to bend a tube with consistent thickness?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98088/how-to-bend-a-tube-with-consistent-thickness/98102#98102)

Or enable the Mesh extra objects add-on.

Then you can create the object directly by adding add pipe joints and choose the shape kind. Of pipes you need

[image]

[How to aproach the modeling of duct work, piping, wiring?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring)

Comment: Yes, I tried this at first but then realised it has a minimum radius of 1cm and my design is smaller than that. But the bridge edge loops worked so all fixed!