# How do I cut an unwanted remaining of an intersection?

Tags: snapping

I have intersected a cylinder with another. I have removed the faces the way I wanted and everything worked.
Now I am trying to remove the layer of the 135 ° cylinder that intersects with the other cylinder.

Below are the images:

[image]

and

[image: 1]

Comment: For shapes like those use the the pipe joints addon. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring/42594#42594

Comment: Thanks! This Solved my problem. I love you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to aproach the modeling of duct work, piping, wiring?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring)