# How can I make a round pipe?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make a roundish pipe for my project. I am not very experienced in Blender yet and this project is very ambitious for me.

Basically, I am trying to make [Pathfinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apex_Legends#Characters) from *[Apex Legends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apex_Legends)*, and I am still at the head part. He has two pipes going around his eye (I will show the image below). To make a pipe, I followed this video tutorial:

*[The Fastest Way to Model Pipe In 5 minutes Blender 2.8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGyhALyruuk&t=118s)*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can work as an alternative for you
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wmu356AoAdw

Comment: You mean like with smooth curvature? Use a Subdivision Surface Modifier

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to aproach the modeling of duct work, piping, wiring?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring)

Answer (score 10):

You can just use a *nurbs path* (or any curve) with a *curve circle* as a [bevel object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/properties/geometry.html?#geometry)...

[image]

Model the curve into place, and choose the circle as the bevel object in the curve>geometry properties and adjust from there.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's going to be hard to properly correct your current pipe. If you bevel your angles, it won't give a good curve on the whole angle. Or you can simply try to apply a *Subdivision Surface* modifier.

Your current shape:

[image]

With a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

If you apply the modifier (here with a subdivision level of 1):

[image]

A fun way to make pipes is first to create with simple vertex extrusions:

[image]

Then bevel the angles (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and tweak the parameters in the *Operator* box):

[image]

Convert your mesh to a [Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) (header menu → *Object* → *Convert To* → *Curve*):

[image]

Then bevel your curve to give it thickness (*Properties panel* → *Object Data* → *Geometry* → *Bevel*). After that, reconvert to mesh, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, and a smooth shading...

[image]

Comment: It worked I made as many vertices as posible and later used Ctrl+Shift+B to add more of them after that I converted it and made it big enough. Its not perfect but i am happy with the result

Answer (score 0):

The answer is patience, you follow the video by making a cube and deleting all but one vertice and then use that vertice to make a pipe/tube. The more vertices you add the rounder the pipe will be.[image]