# Bevel not working

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, bevel

I am trying to make a curved pipe out of this line below : [image]

I made that line by deleting vertices from a cube

I wanted to curve those angles through bevel mode but when I press **Ctrl + B**, that crosshair appears instead of bevel interface.

Pressing **Ctrl + Shift + B** does absolutely nothing either

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes I don't know why ctrl shift B doesn't work right away, anyway you can switch to vertex bevel in the Operator box (on the bottom left of the 3D view)

Comment: Convert the object to a curve and use the bevel in the geometry controls.

Comment: The 'Crosshairs' are preparatory to  creating a Render Region, which is the default keymap for Ctrl-B in Object Mode. For some reason, Blender thinks you're in Object Mode?

Comment: i assume he already converted it to a curve. Then Blender also comes up with crosshair instead of beveling....in edit mode.

Comment: You should see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/209468/86891

Comment: if you are trying to make a pipe then this is not the best way to approach... .In order to make a pipe select the edge in object mode and run convert to curve command from object menu. Then the edge will be curve ,then just go to curve option >geometry> Increase depth step to 1 or 2 (what ever works for you).. then it will look like a sweet pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edges that are not connected to faces cannot be beveled.

> **The Bevel Edges tool works only on selected edges with exactly two adjacent faces.**

Read the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bevel.html?highlight=bevel

You could convert the mesh to a curve and bevel it there, or use another curve as bevel object.

Please read this comprehensive post on how to create pipes:

[How to aproach the modeling of duct work, piping, wiring?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring)

---

Additionally:

In *Object Mode*, <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> will create a Render region, it has nothing to do with bevels or modeling.

Read:https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/regions.html#render-region

You need to be in *Edit Mode* to use the bevel function with the keyboard shorcut <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to do this in *object mode*? You should do it in *edit mode*. Select the vertices in *edit mode*, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. The thing that happened when you did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> was box select. Try doing it in *edit mode*.

Answer (score 0):

For curved piping using curves adjusting them then there is an option for depth so that you can give make it solid using a cube is not good lol

Comment: How comes that making pipes from cubes is not good? That's crazy!