# Hard transitions at 90° Curvatures using Spin Tool

Tags: modeling, objects, shaders, edit-mode, vertices

I wanted to create a simple handle using the Spin Tool and if Shade Smooth or Subdivision Surface is used, there are some hard transitions at the inside of the curvature (where many Verts are placed together very close).

[image]

[image]

Is this simply something one has to live with or is there a trick for avoiding these hard transitions on the inside of the curve?

Face orientation has been checked, doubles are removed, Scale is applied.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66733/how-would-i-smooth-a-90-degree-pipe-angle, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209462/how-can-i-make-a-round-pipe

Comment: It's just like a real world pipe, though.. if you bend it too sharply for its radius, it will kink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could e.g. use this mesh:

[image]

result:

[image]