# How to curve a cylinder

Tags: modeling

I am new to blender and I want to curve a cylinder like in the image below

Any help will be appreciated

[image]

Comment: You might want to read: [How to apporach the modeling of ducts, pipes or wiring](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic way to do it is to switch to top view, select the edge, put your 3D cursor where the center of the rotation is supposed to be:

[image]

Select the *Spin* tool:

[image]

Rotate the edge, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to constrain to 10° by 10°, tweak the Operator box parameters if necessary:

[image]

You could also use a *Curve* modifier but it will be a bit slower

Comment: can you copy your answer to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring to have an all-around post on pipes?

Comment: sure, done...  ;)