# What is the easier method to add a pipe line with bends

Tags: edit-mode

I have created a model of the Vancouver Harbour docks for MS flight simulator.
I would like to add a pipeline attached to the side of some of the docks and wonder what is the simplest and easiest method to do this. I considered creating straight pipe with mesh cylinder but adding curves has me puzzled.
The following images are of the real docks at Vancouver showing the pipelines highlighted in red and also my blender model with (image editor added red lines to indicate where the pipes would go). I am not interested in having any flanges on the pipes just to keep it simple.
Thanks
[image]
[image]

Comment: myabe check my answer here? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-approach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring/210144#210144

Comment: See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTADG1omjVY&list=PL4Dq5VyfewIxxjzS34k2NES_PuDUIjRcY&index=7). You, too, can be a PIPE LORD! :D

Comment: Thanks. They are great tutorials. Now to learn them and put them into practice.

Comment: Thanks. With my limited knowledge of Blender and looking at the different ways (in the 'how to approach the..' post, I am thinking I would use the Vertex Extrusion method as it seems to me to be the easiest the 'wrap the 'pipe' around corners on the fly and correctly follow the sides of the docks ie getting lengths correct for each face of the multiple docks which the pipe needs to go. Please advise if I am wrong. Any way how to you achieve Vertex extrusion? I have worked out to add a single vertex and then extrude but don't know how to 'change direction' when extruding. Also where properties