# How do i bend a cylinder into a Lshape

Tags: 3d-manipulator

How can i bend this cyclinder into an L shape please. I have tried the warp in transform but i seem to end up with an odd windy shape rather than a simple shape.

Simon

Many thanks[image]

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/spin.html

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring) and [Possible Duplicate of](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-create-a-90-joint)

Comment: Related: [How to aproach the modeling of duct work, piping, wiring?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring/42594#42594)